# Powershell goto statement replacement

Tags: powershell, goto

I know powershell doesnt have goto statements. I have a requirement as follows:

```
foreach($x in $xyz)
{
#something works fine
 if($a -eq $b)
 {
  #something works fine
   if($c -eq $d)
   {
    $c | Add-Content "path\text.txt"
   }else
   {
    #Here I need to go to the first if statement, rather than going to foreach loop
   }
 }else
 {
  #nothing
 }
}
```

Have tried break :---- and functions but both doesnt seems to work in my case. When I use break :----, it notifies an error in the last else. When I try to use function as below:

```
foreach($x in $xyz)
{
 #something works fine
  function xyz
  {
   if($a -eq $b)
   {
    #something works fine
    if($c -eq $d)
    {
     $c | Add-Content "path\text.txt"
    }else
    {
     xyz
    }
   }else
   {
    #nothing
   }
  }
 }
```

it is not entering into the function xyz.

Any other suggestions to achieve this.? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You need to start evaluating conditions again starting with the first `if` statement but staying with the current loop variable?

Comment: Functions aren't called when defined they are called when called. Your second attempt never calls the inner function. Add a call to the loop and it will work (and is possibly the right solution here). I would move the function definition out of the loop though.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Yes, becuase I am getting a value from foreach and I need to validate that value in the for loop. Currently when it is going to else, the next time it gets a new value from foreach.

"Add a call to the loop and it will work" - Can you guide me please.?

Comment: What are you doing in your `else` block that can change the value in a way that you need to re-validate especially if you've already failed at least one validation step)? Call the new function in the loop. The same way you call any other powershell function. Right now you are just defining the function but never call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is nested loops:

```
foreach ($item in $data) {

  while (condition $data) {
    # Do stuff, calculate $state

    if (otherCondition($state)) {
      # without label will exit in inner loop only,
      # execution will continue at Point-X.
      break; 
    }

    # more stuff
  }
  # Point-X
}
```

Comment: This might be a year old but very helpful to me today. Thank you for asking it....